# Clicking in a online js button with python

Tags: javascript, python, button, mechanize, html

I'm trying to click on the "Search all flights" button in http://www.priceline.com/ but i'm having some problems.

I know that mechanize doesn't work with javascript so I tried so look on the source code trying to do what the button does but i can't find the function.
There's any other way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using `selenium` ([download link](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium)), which has very heavy support for javascript. [All docs here](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/py/index.html).

Here is a quick example of how you can do that:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.priceline.com/")
driver.find_element_by_id("hotel-btn-submit-retl").click()
driver.close()
```

Comment: Hi i alredy look in to it but i keep getting errors. Can't i use driver = webdriver.Chrome() insted? I keep getting: "WindowsError: [Error 87] The parameter is incorrect"

Comment: How do you setup your chrome browser driver? It should be something like this,from selenium import webdriver

`driver = webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/chromedriver')  # Optional argument, if not specified will search path.
driver.get('http://www.google.com/xhtml');`

Comment: @Findios Also check out this https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver

Comment: @Findios You have to download the chromedriver from https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/downloads/list, and then provide the path from that exe to the method `webdriver.chrome('path/to/chromedriver')`

Answer (score 1):

[Selenium](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium) or a similar library would be the best fit for you. It employs a full browser (Firefox, Chrome, etc.) and gives you a programmable API.