# Is it possible to have python read csv returned from javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, csv

I'm curious if it's possible to read a csv that's returned from a javascript call?

Specifically, on this page:
http://www.fangraphs.com/leaders.aspx?pos=all&stats=pit&lg=all&qual=y&type=1&season=2014&month=0&season1=2011&ind=0&team=0&rost=1&age=0&filter=&players=0

There's an "export data" button.

How can I get Python to simulate a click and then parse the CSV library? I've tried getting it to work with mechanize but am not having much luck. Can someone provide an example?

I'm working in Python 3.

Comment: You wouldn't simulate the click press. What you would do is try to find the HTTP request sent and simulate that.

Comment: That's what I figure, somehow I would get the full url and pass that to urllib -- but how exactly?

Comment: @user2100799 If some content is resulting from running piece of JavaScript code, it is often result of some user interaction. In such a case, http request will come short as it will be missing complete environment of web browser providing JavaScript functionality.

Comment: @JanVlcinsky Just pasting in the url into a browser and clicking export data gives me the CSV I want. Using user2100779's code I get the csv to popup but how do I read it? Wrapping it in urlopen doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using `selenium` ([download link](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium)), which has very heavy support for javascript. [All docs here](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/py/index.html).

Here is a quick example of how you can do that:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.priceline.com/")
driver.find_element_by_id("hotel-btn-submit-retl").click()
driver.close()
```

From: [Clicking in a online js button with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18214795/clicking-in-a-online-js-button-with-python/18214892#18214892)

Comment: This is very close to what I need it to do. How do I capture and read the .csv file that popups?

Comment: Could you just not change the setting of chrome/firefox to auto save in a directory while you code?

Comment: To get content of the page, use `browser.page_source`

Answer (score 0):

In your case the "Export Data" really does not result in visible http request and is pure result of JavaScript code execution.

For this purpose you need to have some sort of web browser.

Check `mechanize` package and related tutorial like here http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/

It allows emulating web browser and doing things like "click" etc.