# Collecting names from website while pressing button to load more names

Tags: javascript, html, button

A colleague asked me this question earlier and I'm honestly not exactly sure how to tackle it.

Basically, there is a website with names (https://www.change.org/p/outrageous-water-bills-let-cpuc-know-that-sjwc-s-unfair-billing-practices-need-to-stop/c?source_location=petition_show).

My colleague is looking to scrape all these names... And is doing it manually thus far. The biggest problem being that there is a "Load More" button toward the bottom which must be pressed again and again in order to load more names.

All of the names are included in the HTML as `<strong class="link-unlined">Example Name</strong>`, so that scraping shouldn't be too hard, but it's the constant button pressing I'm not sure about.

What would be the best way of activating the button over and over without "burning out" the webpage? I think there might be over 10 thousand names here and it only loads like 10 at a time.

The button itself is `<div class="js-load-more"><button type="button" class="btn btn-full btn-big"><span data-loading-text="Loading..." class="text">Load more </span></button></div>`... However, I can't seem to determine how the click itself is being monitored/tracked so I'm not sure if there's a way to just override it?

Comment: What are you using as a backend?

Comment: @Rupesh I was honestly thinking of writing a Python script with Selenium (as in here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18214795/clicking-in-a-online-js-button-with-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon clicking the "Load More" button it calls this API/URL and retrieves the next 10 comments.

https://www.change.org/api-proxy/-/comments?limit=10&offset=0&commentable_type=Event&commentable_id=8256626&parent_id=0&role=comment&before_datetime=2018-04-20T21%3A27%3A01Z

You can call the same link, with modified parameters to get all or next set of comments.

Comment: Okay... So this seems to have a limit of 20... Which it turns out is just the list of ten comments repeated twice? I should be able to write a dynamic script with this (which I'm attempting rn, but might there be an easier way here?)

Comment: I don't think it can get any easier than this. No screen scrapping needed.. the data in JSON format is offering itself at your doorstep :)

Comment: Very fair, I'm writing the script now and will accept this as the answer once I'm done :) thanks for your help!